# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in activity_main xml file

Tags: android, xml

Help Me to FIx this one error in my android project i got this error with main.xml file also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1">
    <WebView android:id="@id/webView1" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/RlayBotm" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <WebView android:id="@id/adsview" android:scrollbars="0" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/welcome" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/img" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:src="@drawable/star" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <ProgressBar android:id="@id/progressBar3" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?unknown_attr_ref: 1010041" android:id="@id/textView1" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:text="Thank You For Using AbhiMovieDownload.com APP " android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:textAlignment="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where you are defining android namespace? ... `"?unknown_attr_ref: 1010041"` it looks like decompiler's output ... are you trying to steal someones work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -1dp instead of only -1 for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="-1dp"
    android:layout_width="-1dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="-1dp"
        android:layout_width="-1dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="-2dp"
        android:layout_width="-2dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RlayBotm"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="-1dp">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/adsview"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="-1dp"
            android:layout_width="-1dp"
            android:scrollbars="0" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="-1dp"
        android:layout_width="-1dp">

        <ImageView
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="-2dp"
            android:layout_width="-2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="-2dp"
            android:layout_width="-2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="-2dp"
            android:layout_width="-2dp"
            android:text="Thank You For Using AbhiMovieDownload.com APP "
            android:textAlignment="4"
            android:textAppearance="?unknown_attr_ref: 1010041" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use this code what i have posted. I believe it will work

Comment: Error:(36, 33) Integer types not allowed (at 'scrollbars' with value '0').

Comment: use this none instead of 0 like this android:scrollbars="none"

Comment: ok thats Gone by Your Above ans now this one

Error:(72, 37) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textAppearance' with value '?unknown_attr_ref: 1010041').

Comment: any id given in the above layout will not work because no + is defined for id

Comment: just put + sign middle of @and id. use like this @+id/yourId